# Is there some way I can have a QML widget affect the content below it with a GLSL shader?

Tags: c++, qt, glsl, qml

I'm trying to create a QML widget with a glazed transparent look; the idea is that I'd like to blur and desaturate whatever the widget is drawn on top of, which should be easy using a GLSL shader.  Unfortunately, it would appear the QML widgets are drawn from the top down, so at the time that I draw a particular widget, the stuff below it hasn't been drawn.  If I reference the contents of the parent widget, it draws all of the child widgets first, which in turn references the content of the parent widget, causing it to draw again, etc.

It seems to be like there ought to be some non-hackish way to achieve this effect.  Does anyone know how to do it?